# MySQL Query to CSV

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Is there an easy way to run a `MySQL` query from the `linux` command line and output the results in csv format?

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
mysql -u uid -ppwd -D dbname << EOQ | sed -e 's/        /,/g' | tee
list.csv select id, concat("\"",name,"\"") as name from students EOQ
```

It gets messy when there are a lot of columns that need to be surrounded by quotes, or if there are quotes in the results that need to be escaped.

Comment: Take a look at `SELECT * from MyTable into OUTFILE`. MySQL reference is on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)

Comment: mysqldump with --tab should be the easy way here with no additional scripting requirements. I wrote [3 ways to convert MySQL to CSV](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/export-mysql-database-table-to-csv-delimited-excel-file)  in detail.

Answer (score 12):

You can use "`INTO OUTFILE`"

I.e.

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE '/ca.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This will create a file "ca.csv" with a comma between each line. There are a few other options like escaping field values, but that should be enough to get you started.

The whole thing:

`mysql -u uid -ppwd -D dbname -e "SELECT a,b,c FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE '/ca.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"`

**EDIT** :- A link for you to look at: [SELECT INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

To escape the fields, you would need to add `FIELDS ESCAPED BY '"'` - This would add double quotes