# Parsing Data from SQLPlus

Tags: bash, awk, sqlplus

Someone kindly dumped the data out of a number of tables in SQL*Plus.

Is there a nice awk or similar script to turn it into CSV or something more easily parsed to load into another system.  Sadly getting it re-run is not an option.
They used

> SQL> set pages 10000 lines 10000

followed by SELECT * from the table

There are the column_names, ---- 's  and then data lines.  It looks like the structure is spaces or tabs between column names and --- ---- with the number of --- probably being field length.  The following is the columns,---'s and first 2 lines from one of the tables.

```
CM D ORDR_REF           LINE_NUM SUPP     BYR       LINE_REVN    TXT_NUM L L T G ACCPT_US A PERF ITEM             MANUF    PART_NO      EC_ CMDTY          CLSFCTN    RCPT_CNT DESCR                    ST IN STORE    EAN       QUOM QTY_ON_ORDR QTY_OUTSTG   QTY_ADVD QTY_ADVD_OUTSTG   QTY_RECV QTY_REJECT     QTY_CR QTY_INVCE_OUTSTG  QTY_INVCD QTY_INVCE_HELD QTY_CR_OUTSTG  QTY_CRDTD QTY_CR_HELD DLVRY_SI DATE_DUE  DATE_ACK  DATE_XPCT DATE_XPED XPED_USR XP LEASE            CMMT_DATE A A   MIN_AUTH   ACT_AUTH CURR_AUTH_SEQ_NUM TAX TAX_DATE  HA PUOM    DSCNT_1    DSCNT_2    DSCNT_3  ENTRD_PRC PRC    MIN_PRC P  ENTRD_VAL MIN_ENTRD_VAL  UNIT_COST VAL_ON_ORDR   VAL_RECV VAL_OUTSTG  VAL_ACCRU VAL_INVCE_OUTSTG  VAL_INVCD VAL_INVCE_HELD VAL_CR_OUTSTG  VAL_CRDTD VAL_CR_HELD VAL_REJECT VAL_CR    VAL_TAX MIN_ORDR_VAL MIN_VAL_TAX L S CNTRCT_REF       CNTRCT_LINE_NUM C GL_TRA AIRCRFT_RE AIRL FLGHT_    LEG_NUM   SRVC_QTY   RATE_PRC   CHRG_VAL UPDT_DATE UPDT_TIME USR_DATA                                                                                                      L VAT_NON_REC_VALUE VAT_REC_VALUE PEV_LINE_COST A
-- - -------------------- ---------- ------------ -------- ---------- ---------- - - - - -------- - ---- -------------------- ------------ -------------------- --- ---------------------- ---------- -------- ---------------------------------------- -- -- -------- ------------- ---- ----------- ---------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ----------- -------- --------- --------- --------- --------- -------- -- -------------------- --------- - - ---------- ---------- ----------------- --- --------- -- ---- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --- ---------- - ---------- ------------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ----------- - - -------------------- --------------- - ------ ---------- ---- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------- --------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- - ----------------- ------------- ------------- -
AR O PO415966              1 040960   LFOSTER       0          0 2 2          Y                                                        Stirrers and cleaning tabs - ivan                            0          0      0       0      0      0      0            0          0          0         0          0       0 CIVIC    01-APR-20 01-JAN-00 01-APR-20 01-JAN-00                      31-MAR-20 0 0          0      0         0 01  01-JAN-00 ER           0          0      0      0          0 1      75.51         0      75.51   75.51      75.51      0          0        0      75.51          0     0      0           0      0      0       15.1        0       0   0                    0   022704                     0      0      0          0 03-APR-20 01-JAN-00                                                                                                       2         0          15.1     75.51
AR O PO415967              1 015552   LFOSTER       0          0 2 2          Y                                                        extras to PO414840 - Sam                                 0          0      0       0      0      0      0            0          0          0         0          0       0 CIVIC    01-APR-20 01-JAN-00 01-APR-20 01-JAN-00                      31-MAR-20 0 0          0      0         0 01  01-JAN-00 ER           0          0      0      0          0 1     60         0     60      60     60      0          0        0     60          0     0      0           0      0      0         12        0       0   0                    0   022705                     0      0      0          0 01-APR-20 01-JAN-00                                                                                                       2         0        12        60
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I know about the SQLPlus function to dump out to CSV (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107279/mysql-query-to-csv), and it would have been nice if this had been used.  It is a 3rd party system where we needed to go through 2 different organisations to get the data, so very difficult to get re-run.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to go externally , but use the csv options natively in sql itself.

Something like this?
[MySQL Query to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107279/mysql-query-to-csv)

Comment: Thanks, I do not have access to the system so getting re-run with set markup csv on
spool myfile.csv is not possible  They went in with putty, and just recorded the putty session and sent it over.  It took over a month to get them to dump the tables this way.  Hence the parsing question.

Comment: Hi Ronaload, While Your Data heading Seems right for CSV, the data inside doesn't seems a good fit. Cz there are space with in the data values and there are no text separators visible. Still can attempt to try with TAB Separator .  You may want to try 
`awk -F'\t' '{print NF}'`  and see the number of fields (NF) returning is same for all lines . if thats good then it may be good for the AWK based processing.

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out the format, was a challenge since it is a mix of tabs and spaces, however it aligned with standard UNIX tabs so **expand** converted the tabs into spaces correctly aligned, and then the **awk** script did the rest.

The column names were white space delimited and then using the --- lines gave the column width to use FIELDWIDTHS for the data.

A couple of bash 1 lines to expand and then process.

```bash
    for f in *.txt;do expand "$f" > "${f%.txt}.fix"; done
```

Then call awk to convert into delimited format

```bash
    for f in *.fix;do awk -f parse.awk "$f" > "${f%.fix}.del"; done
```

The awk script (parse.awk) uses a couple of tricks $1=$1 read everything in using default input FS for line 1 and FIELDWIDTHS after line 2.  The next print outputs using the output file separator (OFS) which is set to ¬ in BEGIN, you can use what you like.  It was not in the data so no need to escape , etc.

> NR==1 prints out the columns

> NR==2 gets the field lengths by measuring the **--- --- -----**

> NR>2 Processes the rest of the file to the end using
> fixed width set in 2

```awk
    BEGIN {
        OFS = "¬"
    }
    NR==1 {
        $1=$1
        print
    }
    NR==2 {
        fw=""
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            fw = fw length($i)+1 " "
        }
        FIELDWIDTHS= fw
    }
    NR>2 {
        $1=$1
        print 
    }
```

Comment: It is reasonably tested since I had about 100 meg of text data across 4 file formats, with between 80 and 140 columns per table.